# Python registry script no output

Tags: python, winreg

Hey Im new to python tried executing my registry change code but got
No output just getting "Process finished with exit code 0".

```
import os
import winreg
def usbenordis(value):
    print(value)
    keyval = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor"
    if not os.path.exists(keyval):
        print("creating key")
        key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyval)
    registrykey= winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor", 0,KEY_WRITE)
    print("open key")
    if value == True:
        SetValueEx(registrykey,"start",0,REG_DWORD,4)
        print("usb disabled")
    elif value == False:
        SetValueEx(registrykey,"start",0,REG_DWORD,3)
        print("usb enabled")
    else:
        print("op cancelled")
        winreg.CloseKey(registrykey)
    return True

def main():
    usbenordis(True)
```

Comment: remove the `try/except` and take a look at what the windows error is

Comment: no error with no o/p other than "Process finished with exit code 0"  after removal as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
if not os.path.exists("keyval"):
```

to this:

```
if not os.path.exists(keyval):
```

You've defined keyval as a variable but you're then passing the *string* 'keyval' to the function.

Also you need to change your boolean values to have uppercase first letters (true = True, false = False)

EDIT: Are you definitely calling the main() function? Try adding the following to the bottom of your code and running (outside of any functions);

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes but no output even after the changes

Comment: I have to assume this is your whole code, if so then try calling the main function like so;

`if __name__ == "__main__":`
     `main()`

Comment: Thanks code worked after using winreg. to winreg items

Answer (score 1):

Working soln

```
import os
import winreg
def usbenordis(value):
   # print(value)
    keyval = r"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR"
    if not os.path.exists(keyval):
      #  print("creating key")
        key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR")
    registrykey= winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", 0,winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
   # print("open key")
    if value == "disable":
        winreg.SetValueEx(registrykey,"start",0,winreg.REG_DWORD,4)
        print("usb disabled")
    elif value == "enable":
        winreg.SetValueEx(registrykey,"start",0,winreg.REG_DWORD,3)
        print("usb enabled")
    else:
        print("op cancelled")
        winreg.CloseKey(registrykey)
    return True

def main():
  #  print("input enable or disable")
    X=input("Input enable or disable:")
    usbenordis(X)


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```